# Javascript hide element (when clicked outside) with certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

So there is much questions here about hiding div when you clicking outside of it. But I have one thing, there is a div(accounts-edit-table-name-edit) which showing hidden div(account-edit-group) on click first. And then - if I will click somewhere else out of the div(account-edit-group) - it must hide. Here is my code where I am trying to do two different conditions (OR):

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
        if($(event.target).parents().index($('.account-edit-group')) == -1 || $(event.target).parents().index($('.accounts-edit-table-name-edit')) == -1)
            {   
                if($('.account-edit-group').is(":visible")) 
                    {
                    $('.account-edit-group').removeClass('acc-edit-f');
                        alert("hiding")
                    }
            }        
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accounts-edit-table-name-edit">"button"</div>
<div class="account-edit-group">block</div>
```

(class "acc-edit-f" just contains "display: block")

Well, if I will click on the div with class "accounts-edit-table-name-edit" - system will immediately show me alert("hiding") though it must look through the conditions and ignore that. Is there any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the jsfiddle if it is what you want :

http://jsfiddle.net/5E6C6/2/

```
 $(event.target).parents().index($('.account-edit-group')) //always return -1
 $(event.target).parents().index($('.accounts-edit-table-name-edit')) // this too
```

Comment: Almost exactly what do I need but div(account-edit-group) could contain other div and if I will click inside on that div - div(account-edit-group) will hide.

Comment: what about now ? http://jsfiddle.net/5E6C6/2/ <-- Ho yea ! give me the points !!!!!

Comment: Nice. Exactly what do I need, thanks. Here is your points ^_^

Answer (score 0):

That's because `parents` doesn't include the first element, which is `e.target`.

Here what you could do :

```
if(!$(event.target).closest('.account-edit-group, .accounts-edit-table-name-edit').length)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead of removeclass

```
$( ".account-edit-group" ).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

1. add the element that is shown/hidden inside  the button
2. stop event propagation when one of the two elements are clicked
3. bind `onclick` event on the document and hide all child elements

here is a working example i wrote for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/T2b4z/2/

```
$(document).click(function(event) {

    var clickedElement = $(event.target);

    if (clickedElement.hasClass('accounts-edit-table-name-edit') || clickedElement.parents().hasClass('accounts-edit-table-name-edit')) {
        $('.account-edit-group').removeClass('acc-edit-f');
        return false;
    }else {
        $('.account-edit-group').addClass('acc-edit-f');
    }
});
```

Comment: Same as I answered below, there could be another one div inside div(account-edit-group), and if you will click on it - div(account-edit-group) will hide. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/T2b4z/1/

Comment: i corrected the code, changed `parent` to `parents` , http://jsfiddle.net/T2b4z/2/